# How use new Firebird 3 client API to connect a 2.5 database?

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

How to setup a DPB to make a client compiled with the new FB 3 API access a remote FB 2.5 database? Is there a way to change WireCrypt and AuthServer in the Database Params Buffer?

i.e.

```
IXpbBuilder* dpb = NULL;
dpb->insertString (&status, isc_dpb_user_name, user);             
dpb->insertString (&status, isc_dpb_password, pass);
```

Is there something like isc_dpb_wirecrypt that could be setup?

Comment: I strongly suggest you ask your question on the firebird-support mailing-list, or maybe even the firebird-devel mailing-list. The new programming API is largely undocumented, and hasn't seen much use (outside Firebird internals) that I'm aware of. However, as far as I'm aware, the client library will default to `WireCrypt = Enabled` and `AuthClient = Srp, Legacy_Auth` (unless explicitly overridden), so connecting to Firebird 2.5 and earlier should just work.

Comment: `Is there a way to change WireCrypt and AuthServer in the Database Params Buffer?` - there should be NONE. Those are security parameters and they should work as set by server administration. If a client, via DPB or any means, can override and substitute server's security settings with ones the client likes better - it is a security hole that is to be reported and fixed before viruses would start using it.

Comment: @Arioch'The That is not true, a client can disable wirecrypt, and if the server requires wirecrypt, the connection is rejected. The reverse is also possible: a client can require wirecrypt, and if the server has it disabled, the connection is also rejected. Similarly, a client can ask for Legacy_Auth, and if the server supports it, that request is honored (although the property is then of course not `Auth_Server`, but `Auth_Client`).

Comment: I’ll try the mailing list. thank you @MarkRotteveel